# Global style isn't being applied

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I have a resource dictionary file as so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TIMS.Common">

<local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ModelLocator" />

<Style x:Key="DefaultWindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DefaultPageStyle" TargetType="Page">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DefaultGroupBoxStyle" TargetType="GroupBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
</Style>
```

And it's included into my App.XAML as so:

```
<Application x:Class="TIMS.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TIMS.Common"
         StartupUri="Views/MainWindow.xaml">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/TIMS;component/Resources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

However, this style doesn't apply unless I specifically set the style in the XAML for that object.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="TIMS.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TIMS.Views"
    xmlns:nav="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Navigation;assembly=PresentationCore"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:valueConverters="clr-namespace:TIMS.Utils.ValueConverters;assembly=TIMS.Utils"
    x:Name="Main"
    Title="Tote Inventory Management System - Southeastern Grocers"
    Width="1024"
    Style="{StaticResource DefaultWindowStyle}"
    Height="768"
    DataContext="{Binding MainWindowViewModel,
                          Source={StaticResource ModelLocator}}">
```

How can I make these the default style without have to explicitly set them on each element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, for example, all your windows in your app to have the same style, remove the x:Key property of your style with TargetType Window.

Having the x:Key property will force you to explicitly use the style in your windows for it to apply. If you remove the x:key, then all the Windows of your app will use that style by default.

Here is a link that explains it with more détails : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx

In short, if you want your style to be global and apply by default to all controls of the TargetType type in your app, do not set a key to your style. If you want the style to be applied only to some of the controls of the TargetType type, set a key to your style and use it explicitly on the controls that will use it.